# jQuery mobile calendars - device support & performance

Tags: mobile, jquery-mobile, datepicker

I'm building a web application for which a datepicker is critical.

As far as I know, there are 2 main options out there:

#### jQuery Mobile Themed DatePicker:

https://github.com/filamentgroup/jQuery-Mobile-Themed-DatePicker

As far as I know, this datepicker was experimental and it wasn't included in jQuery mobile core due to performance issues.

#### jQM DateBox:

http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/

Do you have experience using any of the two?
What devices did you test, how were the results?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another option with jQM Theme integration. Read about it [here](http://blog.mobiscroll.com/jquery-mobile-theme-integration/).